# How can I access the trunk directory of a new Subversion repository?

Tags: linux, svn

I created a Subversion repository along with `branches`, `tags` and `trunk` directories with:

```
svnadmin create file:///home/user/public_html/repo/myrepo
svn mkdir file:///home/user/public_html/repo/myrepo/tags -m "tags created"
svn mkdir file:///home/user/public_html/repo/myrepo/branches -m "branches created"
svn mkdir file:///home/user/public_html/repo/myrepo/trunk -m "trunk created"
```

After doing this, why can't see my trunk directory in `/home/user/public_html/repo/myrepo`? When I run the command `svn ls -R file:///home/user/public_html/repo/myrepo/`, I can see it.

I need to see the trunk directory because I want to create a symlink to work on the app online:

```
ln -s /home/user/public_html/repo/myrepo/trunk /home/user/public_html/dev/
```

How can I make the trunk folder visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The repository directory created with `svnadmin create` is essentially a database where Subversion stores information about files and their versions.

To access the files contained within the repository, you need to check out a working copy using the `svn checkout` command. For example, the following command will check out the repository you created to a directory named `/home/user/public_html/working`:

```
svn checkout file:///home/user/public_html/repo/myrepo /home/user/public_html/working
```

After checking out the repository, the `/home/user/public_html/working` directory would contain `trunk`, `branches` and `tags` subdirectories and you could then create a symlink:

```
ln -s /home/user/public_html/working/trunk /home/user/public_html/dev/
```

For further information, I'd recommend reading the [Version Control with Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/) book (in particular the [Fundamental Concepts](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.basic.html) and [Basic Usage](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.html) chapters).

Comment: and when i commit , the change affect also the working copy or i should always run the command svn checkout file:///home/user/public_html/repo/myrepo /home/user/public_html/working

Comment: @jeddey You only need to run `svn checkout` once. You then make changes in the working copy and run `svn commit` to store a new revision in the repository. The [Basic Usage](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.tour.html) section of the book I linked to covers the work cycle of using Subversion.

Comment: ok now my problem that i can checkout from the working copy , because i need to work on my localhost and after chekout , can you please exalain for me more clear , beacuse what you did said it seems to work if i make modification on the working copy in the server

Comment: @jeddey If you want to be able to use a Subversion repository from more than one computer, then you'll have to set up remote access using either svnserve or Apache. See the chapter on [Server Configuration](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.serverconfig.html) in the Subersion book for details.

Comment: thank you for your help , i solved this with post-commit (y)