# How to create new context menu when right click specific folder the same TortoiseSVN?

Tags: c#, tortoisesvn, contextmenu, windows-shell

I want to add new context menu when right click the specific folder (ex: trunk), trunk folder in SVN repository.
In registry.exe, i can add new context menu into all folder or specific folder (ex:trunk). But i don't know how to determine trunk is folder in SVN repository.

Anyone can give me advise or refer from any document ?
Best regards

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I hope [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37334669/how-can-i-access-the-trunk-directory-of-a-new-subversion-repository) is useful for you

Comment: Hi @PavelAnikhouski. I researched document relevant TortoiseSVN but it don't have information for my problem. I refered from code in Microsoft guideline such as: Create Shell extension, Windows registry information for advanced users,... I read some posts in stackoverflow right click context menu. But i still not have solution for it.

Comment: Thank you @PhongNguyen for help. But it isn't my problem